# Run Microsoft TraceView from CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, driver, drivers

I try to run Microsoft [traceview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553872(v=vs.85).aspx) from CMD, with all flags, verbose level and saving to file.
I tried many combinations but anytime I get a file without real data.

I found Trace View Control Command [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553884(v=vs.85).aspx) but I still not success to run it well via CMD. In additional, it's seems like data is missed. For example, you should found `-flag` or `-level` but how you enable the flags or how you choose the level? in the example you should see `-flag 0x7` - what does this mean?

So my question is how can I run Trace View from CMD, to create a new session and still run an existing workspace.

Until now I tried a lot of variations of the command and I still get an "empty" log file.
These are some of the variations I tried:

```
traceview -start myTracee -pdb myDriver.pdb
traceview -start myTracee -rt -b 1024 -pdb myDriver.pdb -f log.etl
traceview -start myTracee -rt -b 1024 -ft 180 -pdb myDriver.pdb  -f log.etl
traceview -start myTracee -rt -enable -b 512 -ft 180 -pdb myDriver.pdb  -f log.etl
traceview -start myTracee -rt -level verbose -b 512 -ft 180 -pdb myDriver.pdb  -f log.etl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
traceview -start myTrace -rt -pdb myDriver.pdb  -f my.etl -level 7 -flag 0x7fff
```

The log will be saved in my.etl

You must set -level and -flag as described in [traceview help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/traceview-control-commands), the -level and -flag is 0 by default, which will block all trace log.

To set the level and flag values define them in the myDriver.pdb file using this command:

```
traceview.exe -parsepdb myDriver.pdb
```

A *.tmc file will be created, open it with notepad and find the trace level and flag definition inside. With -level 7 and -flag 0x7fff you can get some trace log at least.

To translate the etl file to txt format, use this command:

```
traceview -process my.etl -pdb myDriver.pdb -o mytrace.txt
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I just edited it to add some formatting that quickly helps others understand what's going on.  Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Some years passed but still excellent answer and very detailed! Thank you!  :)